# ymaps.geocode не выводит координаты

Tags: javascript, reactjs, яндекс-карты

Есть код:

```
let coordinate = async (ymaps) => {
    ymaps.geocode(`${city}, ${street}, ${houseNumber}`)
    .then(function (res) {
        console.log(res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates());
    });
    ;}

  console.log(coordinate)
```

Он должен вывести координаты, но вместо этого выводит сам код. Я его проверял в я jsx

Код, в котором он работает:

```
<YMaps query={{ apikey: apikey, load: 'geocode'}}>
  <Map
    modules={["geocode"]}
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    defaultState={{
      center: userLocation || defaultCityCoordinates,
      zoom: zoom,
    }}
    onLoad={ (ymaps) => {
      ymaps.geocode('Москва, Красная площадь')
      .then(function (res) {
          console.log(res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates());
      });
      ;}
    }
  >
```

Comment: Что выводит и какой из консолей? Что дожен выводить? ymaps правильный передается? Как функция вызывается? Откуда вызывается?

Comment: @SwaD выводить координаты объекта в консоль. Думаю, что да, так как это в другом файле работало

Comment: Может быть это потому, что в геокодер вы отправляете какую-то странную строку `${city}, ${street}, ${houseNumber}`, которую он не может переварить? Попробуйте сначала понять, что в Геокодер посылаете. В той же консоли посмотреть быть может.

Comment: «Он должен вывести координаты» — нет, вы же не вызвали функцию. Впрочем даже если вызвать, то ваша функция ничего не возвращает. А когда вы таки попробуете добавить возврат координат, то получите самую популярную проблему на ruSO https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554290/190728